# Custom Operator for Lag or Standard Deviation

Tags: f#, system.reactive

What is the proper way to extend the available operators when using RX?

I'd like to build out some operations that I think would be useful.

The first operation is simply the standard deviation of a series.

The second operation is the nth lagged value i.e. if we are lagging 2 and our series is A B C D E F when F is pushed the lag would be D when A is pushed the lag would be null/empty when B is pushed the lag would be null/empty when C is pushed the Lag would be A

Would it make sense to base these types of operators off of the built-ins from rx.codeplex.com or is there an easier way?

Comment: Do you want a running stdev? If not, you could use `Observable.Aggregate`.

Comment: Would need both running and non-running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In idiomatic Rx, arbitrary delays can be composed by `Zip`.

```
let lag (count : int) o = 
    let someo = Observable.map Some o
    let delayed = Observable.Repeat(None, count).Concat(someo)        
    Observable.Zip(someo, delayed, (fun c d -> d))
```

As for a rolling buffer, the most efficient way is to simply use a `Queue`/`ResizeArray` of fixed size.

```
let rollingBuffer (size : int) o = 
    Observable.Create(fun (observer : IObserver<_>) -> 
    let buffer = new Queue<_>(size)
    o |> Observable.subscribe(fun v -> 
            buffer.Enqueue(v)
            if buffer.Count = size then
                observer.OnNext(buffer.ToArray())
                buffer.Dequeue() |> ignore
        )
    )
```

For `numbers |> rollingBuffer 3 |> log`:

```
seq [0L; 1L; 2L]
seq [1L; 2L; 3L]
seq [2L; 3L; 4L]
seq [3L; 4L; 5L]
...
```

For pairing adjacent values, you can just use `Observable.pairwise`

```
let delta (a, b) = b - a
let deltaStream = numbers |>  Observable.pairwise |> Observable.map(delta)
```

`Observable.Scan` is more concise if you want to apply a rolling calculation .

Comment: How is `ResizeArray` better than `Queue` for this?

Comment: @Daniel You're right. But `Queue<_>` seems to mess with type inference though.

Answer (score 1):

Some of these are easier than others (as usual). For a 'lag' by count (rather than time) you just create a sliding window by using Observable.Buffer equivalent to the size of 'lag', then take the first element of the result list.

So far lag = 3, the function is:

```
obs.Buffer(3,1).Select(l => l.[0])
```

This is pretty straightforward to turn into an extension function. I don't know if it is efficient in that it reuses the same list, but in most cases that shouldn't matter. I know you want F#, the translation is straightforward.

For running aggregates, you can usually use `Observable.Scan` to get a 'running' value. This is calculated based on all values seen so far (and is pretty straightforward to implement) - ie all you have to implement each subsequent element is the previous aggregate and the new element.

If for whatever reason you need a running aggregate based on a sliding window, then we get into more difficult domain. Here you first need an operation that can give you a sliding window - this is covered by Buffer above. However, then you need to know which values have been *removed* from this window, and which have been *added*.

As such, I recommend a new Observable function that maintains an internal window based on existing window + new value, and returns new window + removed value + added value. You can write this using Observable.Scan (I recommend an internal Queue for efficient implementation). It should take a function for determining which values to remove given a new value (this way it can be parameterised for sliding by time or by count).

At that point, Observable.Scan can again be used to take the old aggregate + window + removed values + added value and give a new aggregate.

Hope this helps, I do realise it's a lot of words. If you can confirm the requirement, I can help out with the actual extension method for that specific use case.

Comment: `Buffer` doesn't push until all items are buffered. OP wanted to return `None` when the first item was pushed.

Answer (score 0):

For `lag`, you could do something like

```
module Observable =
  let lag n obs =
    let buf = System.Collections.Generic.Queue()
    obs |> Observable.map (fun x ->
      buf.Enqueue(x)
      if buf.Count > n then Some(buf.Dequeue())
      else None)
```

This:

```
Observable.Range(1, 9) 
  |> Observable.lag 2 
  |> Observable.subscribe (printfn "%A") 
  |> ignore
```

prints:

```
<null>
<null>
Some 1
Some 2
Some 3
Some 4
Some 5
Some 6
Some 7
```

Comment: map/select can get repeatedly applied several times when the pipeline is composed. A map operator having side-effects is a not a good idea.

Comment: Can you give me an example where this doesn't work? The "side effects" are self-contained, not on the "side" where side effects usually are.

Comment: The problem is that while `map` gets reapplied, your original function doesn't.